# List Separator Angular Expression

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Is there a away to comma separate the return from JSON that comes in the structure below so that my result is `blues, brews, barbecue, festival, music`?

My JSON output:

```
"tags": "blues brews barbecue festival music"
```

Using `{{item.tag}} {{$last ? '' : ', '}}` works great on a ng-repeat directive with the below JSON structure. However, my JSON is not formatted like this.

```
[{"tag":"blues"},{"tag":"brews"},{"tag":"barbecue"},{"tag":"festival"},{"tag":"music"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.split()` to convert a string into an array:

```
var arr = "blues brews barbecue festival music".split(" ")
//produces ["blues", "brew", "barbecue", "festival", "music"]
"tags": arr.map(function(el) {
    return {
        name: el,
        href: myHref
    }
})
//produces [{name: "blues", href: ""}...]
```

Just execute this code on your json object after its loaded.

Then you can use this with `ng-repeat`

```
<ul ng-repeat={{tags}}>
    <li>{{tag}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doing a `{{item.event_tags.split(" ").join(", ")}}` gives me the comma list - thanks for that.  Do you know, is there an easy way to add in a href for each item?  As in `<a>blues</a>` ... etc  Thinking i may have to sort that outside of the expression.

Comment: You mean like add an associated href to the `tags` data object?

Comment: Yes so each tag has a link associated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` on the array from using `split`:

```js
var data = {"tags": "blues brews barbecue festival music"};
var tags = data.tags.split(' ').map(function(tag) {
  return {tag: tag};
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(tags, null, 2));
```

but if you are just displaying a string, don't use repeat and just join the split:

```js
var data = {"tags": "blues brews barbecue festival music"};
var tags = data.tags.split(' ').join(", ");

document.write(tags);
```